# while running supervisorctl reread givin an error

Tags: supervisord, django-supervisor

Facing problem on supervisorctl reread

getting this error please help me.

**error**

```
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'supervisor==3.2.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```